# Delegate doesn't work after firing an event WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

I am newly in **WinForms**. So I'll try to give as many details as I could to explain my problem. Sorry for missing anything and if you need other details feel free to ask.

The basic idea is to return a **DataTable** from a dictionary to a **DataGridView** after pressing the Button **"Back".** For this I assume that I have to use delegates. I started learning about them and stuck somewhere but don't know exactly where.

I have 2 classes:

- 1 class is publisher GUI_Mapping in which I have declared the delegate, the event and raise the event like this:

  ```
   namespace Mapping.Forms {
   public delegate DataTable returnDataTableHandler(object sender, GetDataTableIntoDictionary e); 

   public partial class GUI_Mapping : Form {
   public GetDataTableIntoDictionary returnDGVObj = new GetDataTableIntoDictionary();
   public event returnDataTableHandler BackButtonWasPressed;

   protected virtual void OnBackButtonWasPressed()
   {
       if (BackButtonWasPressed != null)
           BackButtonWasPressed(this, new GetDataTableIntoDictionary());
   }
    private void btnBackFromFunctionsMapping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      OnBackButtonWasPressed();
  }
  ```
- Second class is **GetDataTableIntoDictionary** which return a dataTable from a dictionary:

  ```
  public class GetDataTableIntoDictionary: EventArgs
    {
     public DataTable ReturnDataTableByKey(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

      if (dictionaryDGVdatatable.ContainsKey("mappingName"))
      {
          return dictionaryDGVdatatable["mappingName"];
      }
          return null;
    }
  }
  ```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, cause I can receive the dataTable back in DataGridView.
Can somebody, please look through my code and explain what I've missed. I would appreciate it.

Update 1 (full code of GetDataTableIntoDictionary)

```
public class GetDataTableIntoDictionary: EventArgs
    {

        static Dictionary<string, DataTable> dictionaryDGVdatatable = new Dictionary<string, DataTable>();
        private DataTable dt;



        public static void StoreCurrentData(DataGridView dgwDisplayData, string mappingLayerName)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = GetCurrentDataTable.GetDataTableFromDGV(dgwDisplayData);

            var ds = new List<dynamic>();

            if (dt == null)
            {
                //do nothing
            }

            AddDataTableToDictionary(mappingLayerName,dt);
        }

        private static void AddDataTableToDictionary(string mappingLayerName, DataTable dt)
        {
            if(dt != null)
            dictionaryDGVdatatable.Add(mappingLayerName, dt);
        }

        public DataTable ReturnDataTableByKey(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (dictionaryDGVdatatable.ContainsKey("mappingLayerName"))
            {
                return dictionaryDGVdatatable["mappingLayerName"];
            }
                return null;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: where are you subscribing this event ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I'm not sure where I have to subscribe to the event. I thought in the  "btnBackFromFunctionsMapping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)"

Comment: the callling code would subscribe this event actually who is the calling code for this

Comment: @EhsanSajjad can you provide an example please, cause I don't actually understand. GUI_Mapping have to call the delegate after pressing the button. So this delegate will have to return a dataTable

Comment: Always do the null check:  `if(OnBackButtonWasPressed != null) OnBackButtonWasPressed()`. But you don't really need any of this, your `btnBackFromFunctionsMapping_Click()` already is an event (delegate) handler.

Comment: Second snippet does not compile ... there is a "}" missing and `dictionaryDGVdatatable` is declared nowhere.

Comment: @Fildor I have declared it "static Dictionary<string, DataTable> dictionaryDGVdatatable = new Dictionary<string, DataTable>();"

Comment: So you always return the same instance. How do you expect to see change?

Comment: @HenkHolterman is right, actually event is useful when communicating between classes, you have all code in one class right now

Comment: @Fildor Can you please explain how to change this?

Comment: Well, at first I'd use a [`DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Dictionary<string, DataTable>` to begin with ...

Comment: @ Fildor I'll update my post and put the whole code from GetDataTableIntoDictionary

Comment: I need Dictionary because depending on what key I get I return a specific dataTable

Comment: Then set the DataGridView's DataSource to a bindingSource. So you can exchange Tables by setting the bindingSource to one of the DataSet.Tables

Comment: "I need Dictionary" - DataSet's "Tables" Property is DataTableCollection which serves this exact purpose. Advantage using a DataSet: You can persist and load it really easily.

Comment: Initially I've done like this, but the columns with data are added in DataGridView separately and basically I don't have DataSource. That's why when I'm saving all the values, First I save in a DataTable and then this DataTable save in dictionary

Comment: Huh? So you create Columns and copy the data from DataTable into the GridView?? If so, _please_ go consult some tutorials on DataGridView. It makes things so much easier if you just bind it to the DataTable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help, but you know you don't have to be so rude. It's not my fault that I'm working in a project and my colleague added data like this